# AWS: Can I disable/enable RDS multi-AZ daily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, multi-az

I have a mysql RDS instance that is used only from 9am to 9pm.

To avoid too much charges, I would like to stop it during the night, but I cannot do this because I have Multi-AZ active (I need it during server use).

Does it make sense to schedule this process?

@8:45pm:

- disable multi-AZ
- stop RDS instance

@8:45am:

- start RDS instance
- enable multi-AZ

Comment: Why do you "need multi-AZ during server use", and yet do not need the database at night? What is your requirement for having multi-AZ during the day?

Comment: It's a web application that is used in physical stores that are opened only during the day. In the day i cannot risk the DB to be unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good cost-cutting move.

You can create a lambda function (or two) that uses an AWS library (like boto3) to perform this disabling/enabling of multi-AZ and of your RDS instance.

Then, use CloudWatch Events to trigger the lambda function at the times you specify.